# Image is not showing even though path is ok

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, entity

I'm trying to show image using path from database. So generated table for all item to see the results and now I'm trying to make "containers" with images but it isn't showing at all. When I copy path from table and paste it in `<img src="..."/>` image is showing so path is ok, so what is wrong with my code?

I also tried `@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Photo)` but result is the same.

```
@model IEnumerable<KatarzynaKrawczykLab5Zad1.DbContext.Art> 

@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-3">
        <div class="thumbnail">
            <img src="~@item.Photo"/>
            <div class="caption text-center">
                <p>
                    <b>Name:</b> <span>@item.ArtName</span>
                </p>
                <p>
                    <b>Price:</b> <span>@item.ArtDescription USD</span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

image:

[image]

Comment: What is the value of `item.Photo` ? Where are the images stored ?

Comment: Have you tried opening the developer console in your browser to inspect the DOM, view the generated HTML, anything? The browser can be very helpful for these problems.

Comment: value is string and images are stored in ~\Content\ArtImages

Comment: Can yo share a sample value ?

Comment: Ok I have opened developer console and it seems that problem might be with spaces because src look like this: 
<img src="~/Content/ArtImages/coconuts.jpg                  "/>
Because database automatically put them on the end

Comment: https://i.gyazo.com/c0dacc355a2219c36f30870cfe60bdf7.png 
I don't know how to get ride of them

Comment: When you save,make sure you are saving it without extra whitespace. Fix your existing data in database once

Comment: I don't have white spaces anymore but problem still there

Comment: The picture you posted had trailing white spaces. Where did that come from ?

Comment: Problem solved, turned out it's "~" fault